How to configure nginx-ingress access logs to see pod name
I have a general question regarding showing pod name into nginx-ingress access logs.
In my current access log setup, I have see only upstream IP address. However sometimes it`s not so informative since there may be situations when some pod was running couple minutes so upstream ip is not help to understand which pod responded with 5xx response.
log-format-upstream: '{"msec": "$msec", "connection": "$connection", "connection_requests": "$connection_requests", "pid": "$pid", "request_id": "$request_id", "request_length": "$request_length", "remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "remote_user": "$remote_user", "remote_port": "$remote_port", "time_local": "$time_local", "time_iso8601": "$time_iso8601", "request": "$request", "request_uri": "$request_uri", "args": "$args", "status": "$status", "body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent",  "bytes_sent": "$bytes_sent", "http_referer": "$http_referer", "http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent", "http_x_forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for", "http_host": "$http_host", "server_name": "$server_name", "request_time": "$request_time", "upstream": "$upstream_addr", "upstream_connect_time": "$upstream_connect_time", "upstream_header_time": "$upstream_header_time", "upstream_response_time": "$upstream_response_time", "upstream_response_length": "$upstream_response_length", "upstream_cache_status": "$upstream_cache_status", "ssl_protocol": "$ssl_protocol", "ssl_cipher": "$ssl_cipher", "scheme": "$scheme", "request_method": "$request_method", "server_protocol": "$server_protocol", "pipe": "$pipe", "gzip_ratio": "$gzip_ratio", "http_cf_ray": "$http_cf_ray", "http_cf_ipcountry": "$http_cf_ipcountry"}'
So maybe there is a way to show pod name into nginx-ingress logs or maybe you can suggest the way of how to parse upstream_ip to show pod name in logs?
I heard about way to run kubectl get pod | grep <pod-ip> but it seems not so useful since there may be hundred of access log entries and for each we will send API call with kubectl

Refer this similar github issue may solve the problem.
